# How can I prove this relationship between primes and congruences?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Suppose $p$ is prime and $x^2\equiv 1 (\bmod~p)$. Prove that $x\equiv \pm1 (\bmod~p)$. To start, does the statement in the proof imply that $p|(x+1)$ and $p|(x-1)$ or is it an "or" relation. if it is the latter then I do not need help, but if it is the former, then I am stuck. I have so far a proof that shows an "or" relationship.

If $x^2\equiv 1 (\bmod~p)$ then $p|(x^2-1)\implies p|(x+1)(x-1) \implies p|(x+1) \mbox{ or } p|(x-1)$. I can also show that $x\equiv 1(\bmod~p)$ or $x\equiv -1(\bmod~p)$ since $(x+1)(x-1) \equiv 0 (\bmod~p)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strictly one of the statements unless $p=2$: if $p \mid (x+1)$ and $p \mid (x-1)$, then $p \mid [x+1-(x-1)]=2$. Otherwise your thinking is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely an "or" relation, as is usually implied by the "$\pm$" symbol. Indeed, if a prime were to divide both $x+1$ and $x-1$, it would also divide their difference, which is $2$. This is only possible if $p=2$.